# Vuetify date-picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

[This is a vuetify datePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKgB.png)

I need to use it just as a date picker for the given year and month, currently the header is clickable and month and year can be changed.

How do I disable the header?

```
<v-date-picker 
        v-model="2021-07-15"
        no-title
        type="date"
        :show-current = "false"
>
</v-date-picker>
```

Comment: You probably want to set `min` and `max` to the appropriate values, which would theoretically disable the navigation to other months and years...

Answer (score 1):

As Heretic Monkey mentioned you can use min and max with appropriate values. Here is how you can do it:

For the `v-datepicker`:

```html
<v-date-picker :min="min" :max="max" v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
```

And in your script:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    let date = new Date()
    return {
      min: (new Date(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1) - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      max: (new Date(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0) - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      picker: (new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "v-date-picker-header" class and set it to none.

```
.v-date-picker-header {
     display: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: This would certainly hide it visually and may work well in conjunction with the suggestions to set min & max.